# Return receipt in mu4e

Tags: mu4e

How can I use "return receipt" ([Message disposition notifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_receipt)) in mu4e. For composing as well as receiving messages?

For composing I tried to add a "RRT" field in the header, but receiving this mail with thunderbird didn't result in a "return receipt" pop up.

Vice versa I don't know how to make mu4e ask me for Message disposition notification if I receive such an email with mu4e.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `C-c M-n` while writing the message? This at least should cover part of the answer.
Regarding the visibility of the return receipt pop-up in mu4e, according to [this thread](https://github.com/djcb/mu/issues/496) such functionality does not exist at the moment